Unity Freezing When Opening Group of Addressables
I have the following script:
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Settings;
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Settings.GroupSchemas;
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets;

public class MarkFBXFilesAsAddressable : EditorWindow
{
    [MenuItem("Tools/Mark FBX Files as Addressable")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<MarkFBXFilesAsAddressable>("Mark FBX Files as Addressable");
    }

    private string folderPath = "Assets/AddressableAssets/FBXFiles/saved_FBX";

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Mark FBX Files as Addressable", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        folderPath = EditorGUILayout.TextField("FBX Folder Path", folderPath);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Mark All FBX Files"))
        {
            MarkAllFBXFilesAsAddressable();
        }
    }

    void MarkAllFBXFilesAsAddressable()
    {
        string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:Model", new[] { folderPath });
        AddressableAssetSettings settings = AddressableAssetSettingsDefaultObject.Settings;

        if (settings == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Addressable Asset Settings not found. Make sure you have Addressables installed and set up.");
            return;
        }

        AddressableAssetGroup group = settings.DefaultGroup;

        foreach (string guid in guids)
        {
            string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
            AddressableAssetEntry entry = settings.CreateOrMoveEntry(guid, group);
            entry.address = assetPath;
        }

        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        Debug.Log("All FBX files have been marked as Addressable.");
    }
}


I then do:
Tools > Mark FBX Files As Addressable
When navigating through the files I see everything marked as addressable.
I then do:
Window > Asset Management > Addressables > Groups
And when trying to open the Default Group to see my addressables to confirm their existence, Unity freezes on both computers I tried to build this on.
However this may be because there are about 3.5K Assets, in the form of .fbx files totaling ~3GB, in there that I want addressable. The goal here would be to be able to make dynamic scenes with any of the addressable content (2-7 Addressable Assets at a time).
My Hardware may be the limiting factor. This froze in the same place on the following two machines:

Mac Mini Apple M2 Chip 16GB RAM 500GB SSD Ventura 13.4

Lenovo
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
CPU family:          6
Model:               94
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Stepping:            3
CPU max MHz:         4000.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            6799.81


NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650]
250 GB SSD
Ubuntu 22.04
I have the following questions:
Is this freezing for me because of my hardware, or because I am being too ambitious in making this many assets addressable in general?
If it is my hardware can you please recommend ideal hardware for this task?
Is it also possible that a Windows Environment may be better optimized for handling this?
If the answer turns out that I am doomed no matter my hardware/os configuration, can you please recommend a path forward? My intuition is to just save the assets in the Resources folder then build then scenes I need with the assets that way, and forget about doing this using addressables, but I'm a noob to Unity so I would really appreciate some best practices guidance in regard to the ideal architecture here.
